# Alert Me: SMS Text message - How to configure it in SharePoint Online Office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online

How to configure the text message SMS notification in Alert Me functionality in SharePoint Online Office 365?

Comment: This feature is not supported. Probably you try hiding this option from the UI so this won't confuse users.

Answer (score 1):

As per Microsoft this feature is not supported in SharePoint Online.

Also they are stating they have no plans to built this feature.

> Unfortunately SharePoint Online doesn’t support SMS, and we are not planning to undertake such support in the near future. We are, however, working on bringing push notifications on mobile devices. We don’t have any timelines to disclose on this yet.

https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273492-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/7644060-add-support-for-sms-in-sharepoint-online

Answer (score 0):

There is an App (add-in) available in SharePoint App Store  : **SMS for Office (Send SMS Via SharePoint List)** , and **Yes** it works with **SharePoint Online**

- There are zero configurations required from our end (no creating
  accounts with SMS providers)
- Install the add-in and you will get a
  SharePoint list in your site, where you can start sending SMS.
- For SMS Alerts , you would have to make use of SharePoint Designer
  workflow to create an list item entry in the SMS List. (You can use
  the default SharePoint Create a list item action here)
- A completelist of features is available in the company website here : https://timeparity.com/sms-sharepoint
- You can also Search for the app directly in *SharePoint Store (Office Store), the add-in name is "SMS for Office(SMS via SharePoint List)*

[image: Sending SMS From SharePoint]

Answer (score 0):

You can take the cheap work around. Send alert to email and the set up email rule to forward it to mobile device.